# how to manage multi-user permission in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, user-permissions

what is best way to manage multi user permissions and privileges in codeIgniter framework?

I tried to manage it and its working well. But I have to call one function in every controller. that is I am not want to. the function bellow that get controller name and data through session variable.

```
function allow_user_permission(){
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $arr = $ci->session->userdata("userdata")['persissions'];
    $array = json_decode($arr);

    $controller = $ci->router->fetch_class();
    $per = (object) array("label"=>$controller,"val"=>true);
    $permission = array($per);

    if(isset($array)){
      $res = in_array($permission, $array, true);

        if ($res ==FALSE)
            {
             redirect(site_url("dashboard"));
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: use Hooks in ci will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

All you need is creating a parent controller and then make your controllers inherit from it. The parent controller is instanciated each time you access any controller. And its constructor runs the security check.

1- Create file application/core/MY_Controller.php (PS: I shorthanded your code)

```
<?php
class Parent_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->allow_user_permission();
    }

    public function allow_user_permission()
    {
        $arr = json_decode($this->session->userdata['persissions']);
        $permission = array("label" = >$this->router->fetch_class(), "val" => true);
        if (!empty($array) && !in_array($permission, $array, true))
             redirect(site_url("dashboard"));
    }
}
```

2- In your controllers, you just need to update the class from which your controller is inheriting and use `Parent_controller`. example:

```
class Users extends Parent_controller {

}
```